# birt report arabic text not showing in pdf

Tags: report, birt, arabic

Hi I'm trying to enter simple arabic text in a brt report, the arabic text shows fine in the editor, but in the pdf it shows unknown caracters. 
I'm guessing it's some sort of encoding, i tried to use tahoma font (since it includes arabic, ) but same problem.

Any idea how to fix this ?
Thanks

Comment: Does it work when the report runs in html format? If so it is probably "just" a font issue

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue in my application.Its related to font. For that I have created my version of fontsConfig.xml and loaded it on my application start.

EngineConfig class has the following method to load it.

**setFontConfig( URL fontConfig )**