# Arabic Font Not Appearing in Birt 3.7.1 PDF Report

Tags: encoding, fonts, birt, solaris-10, maximo

- Environment: Birt 3.7.1 / Maximo 7.5.0.4 / Sun Solaris 10
- Problem: Arabic Font Not Appearing in Birt 3.7.1 PDF Report generated from Maximo 7.5.0.4 Application running on Sun Solaris 10.
- Details:

  1. Birt Viewer is displaying the report correctly with Arabic font as HTML and MS Word, but PDF is eliminating the Arabic characters completely.
  2. I changed the encoding in both files fontsConfig.xml and fontsConfig.xml from cp1252 to cp1256, in the generated PDF file from Maximo the Arabic letter were replaced by '?'
  3. I changed the encoding from to utf-8 as per advise in one of the web notes, but again Arabic disappeared from the PDF.
  4. The PDF report shows the Arabic correctly from windows environment.

Kindly advise.

Comment: Can be a duplication of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23909640/birt-report-arabic-text-not-showing-in-pdf ?

Answer (score 0):

Birt doesn't understand arabic well, in my case i use a localization which holds Arabic language in it as Unicode

Comment: Thank you for your comment, can you elaborate more on how you are using localization to overcome this issue.